# how do i make addition of two fields in ssrs expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have generated one ssrs report

now i have two fields having values

`1st field value` is `=Fields!FirstNO.Value`

`2nd field value` is `=Fields!SecondNO.Value`

now i have one field `average` and i need to write expression like

average = `(Fields!FirstNO.Value+Fields!SecondNO.Value) / (Fields!SecondNO.Value)`

how can i write above in expression?? directly as i shown or any other syntax is there please help?

Comment: In most cases, (a+b)/b is not an average. Are you sure that `(Fields!FirstNO.Value+Fields!SecondNO.Value) / (Fields!SecondNO.Value)` is *mathematically* correct?

Comment: thats not important please give me answer help me??

Comment: yes i tried above expression but it is giving me 3 outputs :( i don't know why

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it is giving me 3 outputs", for example by providing sample output?

Comment: More details about what you are encountering would be helpful, but maybe SSRS has decided that these columns are strings? You can force a conversion: =CDec(Fields!FirstNO.Value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure these fields are numeric?  Maybe try convert to numeric, like `=cint(Fields!FirstNO.Value)`

Comment: if that it the case the OP would better making sure that the data flowing into the dataset is numeric - use this convert function as last resort